# Запуск модального окна при загрузке страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как запустить модальное окно не по нажатию на ссылку, а при загрузке страницы?

HTML:

```
<a href="#dialog" name="modal">Открыть модальное окно</a>
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
    Простое модальное окно <br>
    <span><a href="#" class="close"/>Закрыть его</a>
    </div>
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);
    });
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Закинуть открытие модального окна в функцию и вызывать её в нужный момен: по загрузке, по клику и т.д. Это можно [сделать так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/VbqGH/)

```
function modalWin(id){
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        modalWin(id); // вызываем по клику
    });
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });
});
modalWin('#dialog'); // вызываем после загрузки
```

Comment: Благодарю :)

Comment: А можно еще вопросик :) А как сделать так, чтобы после закрытия этого окна, человек с данной сессией уже при обновлении этой страницы не получал этого сообщения?

Comment: Можно использовать куки. Для jQuery есть [соответствующий плагинчик](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). По ссылочке найдете и инфу, как его использовать

Comment: Спасибамс :) Добрый человек! Ты наверное единственный меня здесь поддерживаешь :) Мои вопросы все минусуются :(